# Why does JNDI return a DataSource with a NULL uri instead of a lookup failure?

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc, jndi, apache-commons-dbcp

I looked for a similar question, but only found similar ones such as [Godaddy JNDI Problem---Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717870) which doesn't answer my generic question.

Tomcat 7.0.8 .. the following code

```
Context initialContext = new InitialContext();
datasource = (DataSource) initialContext.lookup("java:comp/env/" + "blah");
Connection c = null;
c = datasource.getConnection();
```

throws this error.

```
org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'
   at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1452)
   at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1371)
   at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
...
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
   at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.getProtocol(JdbcOdbcDriver.java:527)
   at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.knownURL(JdbcOdbcDriver.java:496)
   at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.acceptsURL(JdbcOdbcDriver.java:319)
   at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:386)
   at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1437)
   ... 24 more
```

I'm not asking why it failed or how to fix it.

**My question is, why didn't the LOOKUP fail?**

Why did lookup create a useless BasicDataSource with a null URL? Is there a better way to detect if a JNDI name 'doesn't exist' than to try using it and see if it blows up? That approach reminds me of [how they test bridges](http://www.s-anand.net/blog/calvin-and-hobbes-dad-explains-science/).

I finally bit the bullet and moved a bunch of code from raw JDBC code to JNDI, and many mysteries still remain.

I'd like to avoid downcasting the BasicDataSource if possible, to at least preserve an illusion of database independence.

TIA

Comment: People can't cope with lost illusions...

Comment: @Chucky what do you mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I understand JNDI, it is meant for keeping references to *objects* **or** *object factories*.

*Object* business is straightforward - configurer provides a reference to the object, app uses it, as simple as that. But for more complex or generic cases it's more convenient to provide a reference to an *object factory* which gives far more freedom on how objects should be created.

As you haven't posted your webapp's `web.xml` nor Tomcat's `conf/server.xml`, it's hard to elaborate more, but I would guess you have something similar in your web.xml

```
<resource-ref>
  <description>DB Connection</description>
  <res-ref-name>jdbc/myDB</res-ref-name>
  <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
  <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

If you read [Tomcat's JNDI howto](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html), you should see this:

> Providing that Tomcat is able to identify an appropriate resource factory to use to
>   create the resource and that no further configuration information is required, Tomcat
>   will use the information in /WEB-INF/web.xml to create the resource.

Now, let's look at [Tomcat's implementation of the above](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#RP9-mFsAT-A/trunk/java/org/apache/naming/factory/ResourceFactory.java&q=tomcat%20ResourceFactory&l=111). On line 112, you can see that if given `res-type` equals to `javax.sql.DataSource`, it uses `org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory` to create a new data source.

That's it. At this point the job of JNDI is over as it has no influence on how objects are created - and rightfully so! Don't forget that JNDI is meant to be storing references to any kind of objects (mail connections, security realms, etc.). It would be both impossible and unreasonable to write a test for every different type of object. And even so, just by having database settings it would be impossible to determine if these are enough to establish a live connection to the real database.

That's why you have a separate call, `datasource.getConnection()`, and that's why it throws `SQLException` which you are supposed to catch and handle.

p.s. you could possibly argue that `BasicDataSourceFactory` should be more smart and have a list of mandatory properties/arguments. Maybe. But this is the subject to another question, as originally you have asked *why didn't the LOOKUP fail*  ;)

Comment: thanks, I think I'm understanding a little bit better. I didn't post conf/server.xml because my question wasn't, "how do I make this work". But, I do have a similar resource-ref in my web.xml, and no matching <Resource> reference.   (Perhaps I should have asked the question as, "how do I detect when the user hasn't provided a <Resource> entity?"

It sounds like the answer to my questions that the lookup didn't fail because it found the <resource-ref> object, but the DataSource returned has a null URI because the <Resource> was not found.

Comment: re-reading the JNDI howto, Resource and resource-ref are basically equivalent. So, my lookup() succeeded because I have a resource-ref somewhere.  Your last comment, then is exactly what I should have asked: "why isn't BasicDataSourceFactory … more smart and have a list of mandatory properties/arguments". So, I think you've answered my question.

Comment: As a side note, I think I would choose another data source factory (e.g. c3p0) for my next project as I'm not very happy about dbcp (not because of JNDI but for other reasons). Unfortunately, it's not that simple to replace a low-level library with something else, would require loads of testing, and testing edge cases is particularly hard.

Comment: thanks. DBCP is better than nothing (and 'free' in tomcat), but I looked at c3p0 also.

Answer (score 1):

When running a war file on tomcat, the web.xml and server.xml will work together to give you the definitions as described here.  Sometimes, in Eclipse, you may be using a different web.xml than you think.  Make sure the debugger in Eclipse is loading the web and server.xml files that you expect. I found in my case that the web.xml didnt have the definition, so added it there and this worked.

Comment: That's a true statement, but it's (1) more of a comment than an answer (and so should be entered as a comment), but (2) doesn't answer my question. As I mentioned in the other thread 3y ago, I'm not asking how to make my app work, but asking about JDNI behavior. Thanks for trying to answer and welcome to SO!